# Is there a way to force path.normalize to use windows / mac path format?

Tags: node.js, path

Essentially i'm composing an email through code and would like to append to that email two file paths to a file on the server, one for mac users and one for windows users to click, is there anyway to generate both of these regardless of what machine i'm on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with node v0.12 you can access the [`path.posix`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_posix) and [`path.win32`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_win32) namespaces if you want to access those particular platforms' path handling behaviors. So for Windows path normalization you'd use `path.win32.normalize()`.

Comment: path.posix.normalize('c:\\oi.txt') -> 'c:\\oi.txt'  what??

Comment: @BernardoDalCorno Why are you surprised? There is nothing to transform/normalize in that particular case, the original path is a valid POSIX path (a file/dir/etc. in the current directory).

Comment: The question asked for a way to force path.normalize to use windows / mac path format. I found out posix and win32 will use the right separator, but not convert it. So we're better of doing somepath.replaceAll(path.posix.sep, path.win32.sep) for instance